# Aplicação android inciando com Menu Drawer lateral sempre aberto

Tags: java, android

É uma questão bem simples, mas como posso resolver esse problema?
Toda vez que inicio a aplicação ela está com aquele menu lateral suspenso sempre aberto.

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

/**
 * Remember the position of the selected item.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

/**
 * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the
 * user manually expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
 */
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

/*
 A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
 */
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

/**
 * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
 */
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private LinearLayout mDrawerLinearLaryout;
private ListView mDrawerListView;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated
    // awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of
    // actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerLinearLaryout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragmento_menu_drawer, container, false);

    mDrawerListView = (ListView)mDrawerLinearLaryout.findViewById(R.id.lvListaMenu);

    String[] itens ={   getString(R.string.inicio),
                        getString(R.string.sobre),
                        getString(R.string.opcoes),
                        getString(R.string.fica_tecnica)};

    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar()
            .getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1, itens));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);

    mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            if(position==0)
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new Fragmento_ListaPragas()).commit();
            if(position==2){
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),ActivityOpcoes.class));
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        }
    });
    return mDrawerLinearLaryout;
}

public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    return mDrawerLayout != null
            && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}

/*
 Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation
 drawer interactions.

 @param fragmentId
            The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
 @param drawerLayout
            The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
 */
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.navigation_drawer_open, /*
                                     * "open drawer" description for
                                     * accessibility
                                     */
    R.string.navigation_drawer_close /*
                                     * "close drawer" description for
                                     * accessibility
                                     */
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to
                // prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true)
                        .commit();
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce
    // them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView!= null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(
                "Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar.
    // See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the
    // action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/*
 Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to
 show the global app 'context', rather than just what's in the current
 screen.
 */
private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}

private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}

/**
 * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must
 * implement.
 */
public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    /**
     * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
     */
    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
}
}
```

Comment: Cole o código aqui para a gente ver. Talvez, caso tenha reutilizado o exemplo do Google, ele verifica, baseando-se em sharedPreferences, se o Drawer já foi exibido. Então, ele pode não estar marcando a variável como true, ou seja, ele foi exibido, e toda vez que entra, como ela ainda está false , ele é reaberto.

Comment: Ok, adicionei o código.

Comment: Conseguiu, amigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque para FALSE nesse trecho

ORIGINAL:

```
mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true);
```

COM A MUDANÇA:

```
mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);
```

Isso por que no trecho abaixo ele só marca a variável no SharedPreference se for false, porém o default lá em cima está true. Ou seja, se essa variável não existir no SharedPreference, o default será true, mas lá embaixo, no evento de open do Drawer ele só entra para marcar como true, ou seja, o usuário já aprendeu sobre aquilo, caso a variável esteja false, mas como ela vai estar false se o default na inicialização é true?!

Por isso faça a troca de default true por false.

```
              if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {  // o default lá em cima é true, como vai entrar aqui?
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to
                // prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true)
                        .commit();
            }
```

Comment: Obrigado não sei ao certo se foi bem isso, eu fussei tanto o código, que parou de aparecer, mas fiz o que você pediu, mas depois eu seto pra true e continua não abrindo mais, por precaução deixei false mesmo como voce  pediu pra fazer. Mas de qualquer jeito, obrigado.